# Using windows 8.1 in a company

Tags: windows, windows-8, microsoft-account

We migrated a few of our PC's to Windows 8 and are now facing the problem that you are forced to register a Microsoft account in order to access the 8.1 Update and/or use office 2013. We dont feel like registering a new account for each and every PC we buy and keep track of all these accounts, and also down feel like having a single account for all pc's. Is there a way to avoid this account requirement at least in the professional version of Windows?
What would your choice be inside a company?

Comment: Simply use a full setup medium.

Comment: We dont have it. We have the 8.0 DVD and have to update via the store.

Comment: There's a [standalone version](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search/DownloadResults.aspx?q=KB2919355) of the Windows 8.1 Update. No Microsoft Account is required to download it.

Answer (score 0):

Does this page help?

[How to download the official Microsoft Windows 8.1 ISO](http://www.cnet.com/au/how-to/how-to-download-the-official-microsoft-windows-8-1-iso/)

Answer (score 0):

Use group policy to disable Microsoft accounts.  Open gpedit.msc and go to

```
Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options
```

> Accounts: Block Microsoft accounts
>
> This policy setting prevents users from adding new Microsoft accounts
>   on this computer.
>
> If you select the "Users can’t add Microsoft accounts" option, users
>   will not be able to create new Microsoft accounts on this computer,
>   switch a local account to a Microsoft account, or connect a domain
>   account to a Microsoft account. This is the preferred option if you
>   need to limit the use of Microsoft accounts in your enterprise.
>
> If you select the "Users can’t add or log on with Microsoft accounts"
>   option, existing Microsoft account users will not be able to log on to
>   Windows. Selecting this option might make it impossible for an
>   existing administrator on this computer to log on and manage the
>   system.
>
> If you disable or do not configure this policy (recommended), users
>   will be able to use Microsoft accounts with Windows.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj966262.aspx

[image: Block Microsoft Accounts]